# any pin change interrupt in my avr microcontroller cause a micro reset

Tags: c, gcc, interrupt, avr, microchip

I'm coding with Microchip studio for an ATmaga644p microcontroller.
I just want to activate pin change interrupt on my microcontroller for pinA.1, A.2, A.3.
But the problem is that when I activate it, with every interrupt signal the microcontroller will reset.

This is how I write my code to it:

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(PCINT1_vect)
{
}


/*************************************************************************
Function: ISR(PCINT2_vect)
Purpose:   
Input:   
Returns:  
**************************************************************************/
ISR(PCINT2_vect)
{
    
}


/*************************************************************************
Function:ISR(PCINT3_vect)
Purpose: 
Input:    
Returns:  
**************************************************************************/
ISR(PCINT3_vect)
{
    
}
/*************************************************************************
Function:void init_pin_change_INT(void)
Purpose:  
Input:
Returns:  
**************************************************************************/
void init_pin_change_INT(void)
{
    //enable Pin chane interrupt for PortA.1 , PortA.2, PortA.3
    PCMSK0|=(1<<PCINT1)|(1<<PCINT2)|(1<<PCINT3);
    //enable PCMSK0 interuppt 
    PCICR |=(1<<PCIE0);
}
void main (void )

{
cli() ;
init_pin_change_INT(v);
sei();
while (1)
}
```

When I disable all the pin change interrupts, the code works well but every one of the interrupts that I enabled when a signal coming cause a reset.
Also, the code have another parts, but I just write the needed one.

Comment: Your program won't even compile due to syntax error; maybe you can fix that. And to reproduce, it's always helpful to know the command line to call avr-gcc / avr-g++.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Data Sheet of the ATmega644, I came to the following conclusion:

Ports A1, A2, A3 can be configured for pin-change interrupts for PCINT1, PCINT2 and PCINT3, respectively.

Now PCINT0 ... PCINT7 will **all trigger the same interrupt**, which is `PCINT0_vect` in avr-gcc. Which of these pins will be enabled for that feature can be controlled by setting respective mask enable-bits in `PCMSK0`:

```cpp
PCMSKO |= (1 << PCINT1) | (1 << PCINT2) | (1 << PCINT3);
```

In order to enable pin-change IRQ 0 (which gathers 8 individual pins), is controlled by setting the respective bit in `PCICR`:

```cpp
PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);
```

As said, all these pins will trigger the same IRQ, thus:

```cpp
ISR (PCINT0_vect)
{
    // Your code.
}
```

However, as it appears there is some typo / inconsistency in the data sheet:

> PCIFR.PCIF0: When a logic change on any PCINT7..0 pin triggers an interrupt request, PCIF0 becomes set (one). If the I-bit in SREG and the PCIE0 bit in EIMSK are set (one), the MCU will jump to the corresponding Interrupt Vector.

But EIMSK has only bits INT0..2.  Presumaly, they mean bit PCIE0 in PCICR.

Apart from that, my recollection is that you have to check by hand *which* pins actually changed. To that end, it might be useful to remember the state of PORTA:

```cpp
// Must be initialized to PORTA in main or startup-code.
uint8_t volatile porta_old;

int main (void)
{
   // Init PCINT1..3 which belong to Pin-Change IRQ 0.
   PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);
   PCMSKO |= (1 << PCINT1) | (1 << PCINT2) | (1 << PCINT3);
   PCIFR = 0xff;
   porta_old = PORTA;
   sei();

   // ...
}

ISR (PCINT0_vect)
{
    uint8_t porta_now = PORTA;
    uint8_t porta_change = porta_now ^ porta_old;
    porta_old = porta_now;

    // Your code evaluates bits of porta_change.
}
```

Unfortunately, there is a name clash because `PCINT0` is just a bit in `PCMSK0`, and there is also `PCINT0_vect` which collects PCINT0..PCINT7.

---

> any pin change interrupt in my avr microcontroller cause a micro reset

This is because you didn't implement `PCINT0_vect`.  The default action for non-implemented ISRs is `__bad_iterrupt`, which jumps to `__vector_default`, which in turn defaults to the reset vector.

Apart from that, all of `PCINT[123]_vect` is dead code.